# Сделать разные версии REST API с помощью генерации их через openapi

Tags: java, maven, openapi

Имеется необходимость сделать версионирование REST api.

Изначально была спецификация:

```
openapi: "3.0.2"
info:
  title: "API"
  description: "API"
  version: "1.0.0"
servers:
  - url: "http://server/api/v1"
paths:
  /process/start: ...
  /request/limit: ...
components: ...
```

После компиляции были сгенерированы интерфейсы:
ProcessApi, RequestApi, ProcessApiDelegate, RequestApiDelegate

Я подумал будет просто и поменял так:

```
openapi: "3.0.2"
info:
  title: "API"
  description: "API"
  version: "1.0.0"
servers:
  - url: "http://server/api"
paths:
  /v1/process/start: ...
  /v2/request/limit: ...
components: ...
```

И к моему удивлению, но вполне конечно законно сгенерились интерфейсы:
V1Api, V2Api, V1ApiDelegate, V2ApiDelegate
что естественно не подходит при имеющемся коде на первую версию рестов.

Можно как-то заставить пропустить первый параметр(v1,v2) и генерить файлы как обычно?

Или ещё один вариант как-то указывать какой сервер("http://server/api/v1" или "http://server/api/v2") использовать для каждого реста?

Ну или другие любые примеры которые мне помогут решить эту задачу :(

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Решил, добавив в configOptions строку

```
<useTags>true</useTags>
```

И прописав необходимый нейминг в тегах

```
tags:
 - Process
```